nvm use <version> && npm run start, can't be combined?
On a Windows 11 Git Bash/VS code terminal, attempting to write a one liner that would run set the nvm version to use and then start up npm.
There are no issues when running these 2 commands separately (without &&):
$ nvm use $(cat .nvmrc)
Now using node v16.19.0 (64-bit)
$ npm start
# Starts up

Note: $(cat .nvmrc) just grabs the node version to use from .nvmrc ex. v16.19.0
When combined into a one liner though, the second command npm start errors out.
$ nvm use $(cat .nvmrc) && npm run start
Now using node v16.19.0 (64-bit)
bash: npm: command not found

Any idea how to get the one liner to set the version and then npm run start successfully?
UPDATE:
Here are my env vars in case it helps:


Doesn't really answer your question but does it work if you use ; instead of &&?

The combined command works fine in my case (using Windows 10 Git Bash/VS code terminal), so there should be something else

@Phil Tried that too, didn't work.

@qrsngky that's odd, it always errors out on me as seen above, not sure why or how to resolve it..

What version of nvm do you have?

I have nvm version 1.1.12

I also have nvm 1.1.12 so that's not the problem. I have this for bash: GNU bash, version 4.4.23(1)-release (x86_64-pc-msys) from 2016. And /nvm/nodejs is part of $PATH

@qrsngky updated question with the relevant env vars in case it helps

I can reproduce the problem in another computer with Windows 11, but I still can't figure out the cause. I can use npm use 18 && powershell npm run dev to run npm in git bash, though. Another test: which npm works fine by itself but somehow not after &&, it told me that there's no npm in ($PATH)
